# Why can't I instantiate a managedbean in jpa?

Tags: jpa-2.0

I am trying to develop a small web application as training for my upcoming finals and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

These are my **Entities**L `Kunde` and `Konto` (many2many-relationship), the auto-created table `Kunde_Konto` has only the two primary keys of my entities.

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="findKundeById", query="select k from Kunde k where k.svnr = :svnr"),
})
public class Kunde implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(precision=4, scale=0)
    private Long svnr;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Konto> konten;
}

@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="findKontoByBesitzer", query="select k from Konto k join k.besitzer b where b.svnr = :svnr")
})
public class Konto implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(precision=4, scale=0)
    private Long knr;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="konten")
    private List<Kunde> besitzer;
}
```

And this is my **Managed Bean**:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class KundenKontoList implements Serializable {
    private FacesContext fc = null;
    private HttpServletRequest hsr = null;
    private HttpSession hs = null;

    @EJB
    private KontoFacadeLocal kontoFacade;

    @EJB
    private KundeFacadeLocal kundeFacade;

    private Kunde k;
    private List<Konto> konten;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of KundenKontoList
     */
    public KundenKontoList() {
        fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        hsr = (HttpServletRequest) fc.getExternalContext().getRequest();
        hs = hsr.getSession();

        k = (Kunde) hs.getAttribute("kunde");
        konten = kontoFacade.findKontoByBesitzer(k);
    }
}
```

The exception

```
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Klasse at.pf.controller.KundenKontoList kann nicht instanziiert werden.
```

which translated means that `KundenKontoList` can't be instatiated, is thrown at the line:

```
konten = kontoFacade.findKontoByBesitzer(k);

//method in the facade:
@Override
public List<Konto> findKontoByBesitzer(Kunde k) {
    Query q = em.createNamedQuery("findKontoByBesitzer");
    q.setParameter("svnr", k.getSvnr());
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

I think that it has something to do with the `kontoFacade`, but I don't know what the exact problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Fail on init of managedbean, suggests to me that injection of ejbs is failing. Is there a longer error message?